# Continuous UV for effects in high resolution

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, effects

I'm trying to get better at UVs and what I have here is an object, that needs to be UV unwrapped the way so that, for example, when I offset a black and white texture on the Y axis, the white part will go around it in a circle following the edge flow (attached image).

The solution I came up with was straighten the UVs and put them next to each other. But with that comes a lot of problems. For example, since I had to scale it down so much it will have poor resolution. Also when using addons like UV packer it doesn't recognize the two separate parts of the mesh as one and puts them far apart, removing the idea of texture making the full circle.

What is the best way to achieve that and what am I missing?[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind the texture to be the same radially you can overlap your UVs vertically

Comment: I don't want it to overlap, that would solve the long UV problem

Answer (score 0):

An option might be to abandon from-map UV mapping altogether, and map the 0-1 UV Space to polar coordinates in Object Space:

[image]

Comment: I will eventually have to export it into a game engine and also use other apps so this is not an option. It's also very stretched and I have to avoid that too.

Comment: Okydoky .. (stretching is inevitable? There's a singularity at the center.)

Comment: There's some stretching near the center but not as bad as on the picture (I was trying to fix that too but didn't figure out how). Maybe because there's more edge loops. Also the mesh gets cut off in the center so no singularity.

Comment: @DavidElucard probably not helpful, again .. but if you create a 0-height baseless cone instead of a circle, the default unwrap looks a lot better for you.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. But yeah, the main problem there would be the "singularity" and stretching :/ I actually thought it was something simple but now I see why people hate UV part of modeling so much